# Current method for accessing databases by .NET

Tags: c#, database

So in Java they have a generic JDBC connection layer for connecting to most databases (SQL ones anyways).

What is the most current equivalent in .NET if I am targetting .NET4.0 or .NET4.5 (if it differs). A link to a tutorial would be nice also.

I did try googling but came up with quite a few results and different code segments all doing what appears to be the same thing and I have no idea which ones are current. OLEDB and ADO.NET came up alot so I assume it will be one of these. There appears to be multiple versions of ADO.NET also.

Comment: Aren't `Linq-to-SQL` (dbml) is the most *current* one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.NET is the standard data-access plumbing for most common databases; however, *above* that, it is pretty common to use tools such as Entity Framework, NHibernate, "dapper", etc. You shouldn't be using OLEDB or ODBC without good reason. There aren't "multiple versions of ADO.NET" - however, there are multiple .NET framework versions, and each of those will have incremental ADO.NET changes.

If you are using a more esoteric RDBMS, you may have to use a different access technology.

Comment: Thanks...did a search for ADO.NET4 and came up with a microsoft link. I believe an entity framework will be useless to me as I will be running adhoc SQL queries from adhoc databases (Correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: @Cheetah yes, that is not a good scenario for EF; "dapper" might still be useful, though.